# Stop/Start Uniface service on a Win 2008 server

Tags: windows, service

Trying to restore a SQL database on a test system, but can't because a [Uniface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniface_%28programming_language%29#History_of_Uniface) service keeps connecting to it. Looks like Uniface 9.4.

Having trouble finding much documentation on this venerable old Uniface platform. Does it have a service name in Windows? Or does it run as a lower-level process?

Any pointers to documentation greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the uniface urouter service and that will stop the uniface application servers and prevent any client processes from connecting. Once done, restart the urouter. I am making a few assumptions about your setup, so if this fails to help, take the ungraceful approach of killing the following processes (uniface.exe, idf.exe, userver.exe). If you have uniface flow installed and running, there are other processes to stop too, but for now, I will assume you are not running that.

Answer (score 2):

Revoke all permission from all users except a newly created system user. Now connect using that user and kill all other running connections/sessions. You can continue doing maintenance work. After that restore permission.

Should work on any SQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is in the installation folder. A lot of information can also be found at:

http://www.uniface.info/

It is very active and you can download a trial of the latest Uniface release.